# how can I calculate the probability to get triples or better when throwing n 6-sided dice?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-distributions

I've been banging my head on a wall with this question. I'm designing a game and would like to implement a loot system inspired by a game called "Vermintide" where players roll a certain number of dice and gain loot according to the result.

I want my players to get rewards depending on the result of the dice. but I need to evaluate the quality of items, and the number of dice they get to throw based on the probability.

Essentially if they get doubles they get a standard item, if they get triples they get a magic item etc...

I heard of the "birthday problem" and "multinomials" but most of what I could find about it seemed to be very particular cases (I found birthday problem for 2 or more but not for 3 or more, which seems much less trivial).

Is there a smart way to go about this problem which I first thought was going to be trivial, and the more I search the more it seems complicated.

Comment: What does 'triples or better' mean precisely?

Comment: How many dice participate in one roll?

Comment: @StefanMesken
Triples or better is 3 or more of a kind

Comment: @Vasya the number of dice is variable. I want to make an excel sheet with the probability for each number of dice

But it's always going to be between 3 and 12

Comment: Standard (fair) six-sided dice?

Comment: There is a.form at the bottom of this page that will do the calculation automatically, and the attached article explains how the calculation is done: https://blog.plover.com/math/yahtzee.html

Comment: @MJD thanks, looks like that pretty much covers my needs. Could you re-post this as an answer so I can credit you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The OP is correct in saying that this is a generalization of the Birthday Problem and that it is harder because we are interested in cases where the number of people with the same birthday is greater than two.  One approach is by way of exponential generating functions.

Let's take a concrete example.  Suppose we want to roll $10$ six-sided dice and find the probability that at least one number comes up $5$ or more times.  It seems easier to consider the complementary event, i.e. all numbers come up $4$ or fewer times.  There are $6^{10}$ possible sequences of die rolls, all of which we assume are equally likely.  We would like to count the number of sequences in which no number comes up more than $4$ times.  We generalize the problem a bit and think about a sequence of $n$ die rolls, and let the number of sequences in which no number appears more than $4$ times be $a_n$.

The exponential generating function of $a_n$ is defined to be
$$f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n!} a_n x^n$$
Since each die has $6$ sides and each number appears no more than $4$ times,
$$f(x) = \left( \sum_{i=0}^4 \frac{1}{i!} x^i \right)^6$$
The number we want in our problem, $a_{10}$, is $10!$ times the coefficient of $x^{10}$ when $f(x)$ is expanded.  I suppose a pencil and paper solution is possible, but I took the easy way out and used a computer algebra system to find that the coefficient of $x^{10}$ is $2177 / 144$.  Therefore the number of sequences of $10$ die rolls in which no number appears more than $4$ times is $$a_{10} = 10! \times \frac{2177}{ 144} = 54,860,400$$

So the probability that no number appears more than $4$ times in $10$ rolls is 
$$p = \frac{a_{10}}{6^{10}} = 0.907291$$
and the probability that at least one number appears $5$ times or more is
$$1-p = 0.0927093$$

Answer (score 2):

In what follows I will refer to “pattern” in the dice rolls.  For example the pattern `AAABC` means that three of the dice show the same number and the other two dice are different from the first three and also different from each other.  The roll $1 2 2 4 2$ has this pattern, but $1 2 2 1 2$ does not; that has the pattern `AAABB`, and similarly $2 2 2 2 1$ is not pattern`AAABC` but `AAAAB`.

There are seven patterns possible with five dice:

```
AAAAA
AAAAB
AAABB
AAABC

AABBC
AABCD
ABCDE
```

If you want three of a kind “or better” on five dice, you are interested in the sum of the first four patterns and you want to disregard the other three.  What follows is an explanation of how to compute the probability for each pattern.

We will represent the patterns numerically like this: `AAABC` will be $(2, 0, 1)$ because there are two letters that appear once, no letters that appear twice, and one letter that appears three times.  `AAABB` will be $(0, 1, 1)$ because there are no letters that appear once, one that appears twice, and one that appears three times.  `AABCD` is $(3, 1)$  (we omit the trailing zero) and `ABCDE` is $(5)$.  We'll refer to these numbers as $n_1, n_2, \ldots$.  For `AAABC`, we have $n_1 = 2, n_2 = 0, n_3 = 1$.  For five dice, the representations of the seven patterns are:

$$\begin{array}{lrrrrr}
  & n_1 & n_2 & n_3 & n_4 & n_5 \\
AAAAA & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
AAAAB & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
AAABB & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
AAABC & 2 & 0 & 1 \\
AABBC & 1 & 2 \\
AABCD & 3 & 1 \\
ABCDE & 5
\end{array}
$$

Now suppose we're rolling $N$ dice each with $d$ sides. If there are $N$ dice, we should always have $\sum i\cdot n_i = N$.  We'll also take $k=\sum n_i$; this is just the number of different letters in the pattern.

Then it transpires that the number of ways of rolling any pattern is:

$$ 
\color{maroon}{d\choose k}\color{darkblue}{k!}
{\color{darkgreen}{N!}\over \color{purple}{\prod {i!}^{n_i}{n_i}!}}
 $$

To get the probability, just divide by $d^N$.

I'll work through one example to demonstrate the formula.  How many ways are there to roll the pattern `AAABC`, which is three of a kind, but not counting full house, for of a kind, or five of a kind.  For `AAABC` we have $n_1=2, n_2=0, n_3 = 1$, so $k=n_1+n_2+n_3 = 3$, and the formula gives:

$$\color{maroon}{6\choose 3}\color{darkblue}{3!}
{\color{darkgreen}{5!}\over \color{purple}{(1!^2\cdot2!)(2!^0\cdot0!)(3!^1\cdot1!)}} =
\color{maroon}{20}\cdot \color{darkblue}{6}\cdot
{\color{darkgreen}{120}\over \color{purple}{2\cdot1\cdot6}} = \mathbf{1200}
$$

There are 1200 ways to roll the pattern `AAABC`, so the probability is $\frac{1200}{6^5} \approx 15.43\%$.  Similar calculations for the other three patterns of interest give:

$$\begin{array}{lrrl}
A A A B C & 1200 & 15.43  & \% \\
A A A B B & 300 & 3.86 \\
A A A A B & 150 & 1.93 \\
A A A A A & 6 & 0.08 \\ \hline
\text{Total} & 1656 & 21.30 & \%
\end{array}
$$

So you can expect to get three of a kind or better around one time in five.

(By far the most common pattern is the single pair `AABCD`, which occurs almost half the time.)

I explained the formula in more detail [in a blog post](https://blog.plover.com/math/yahtzee.html).  [This page tabulates the probabilities for every pattern of up to 12 dice](https://perl.plover.com/misc/enumeration/Dice).  You program that generated these tables is available online: the URL

```
    https://perl.plover.com/misc/enumeration/tabulate-dice.cgi?N=7&S=11
```

generates a table for seven dice each with 11 sides.  You can adjust the 7 and 11 to suit yourself.  [Related materials](https://perl.plover.com/misc/enumeration/), including program source code, are available also.

Comment: Confirmed by simulation (+1): If you sort the outcomes from 5 dice, you're asking for the longest run length to be at least three.  In R, the function `rle` (for 'run length encoding') does most of the work: three lines of code: `set.seed(731);  m=10^5;  die = 1:6`, `x=replicate(m,max(rle(sort(sample(die,5,rep=T)))$lengths))`, and
`mean(x >= 3)` return 0.21219, which matches your 0.213 within the margin of simulation error.

Comment: Is there a nice way to calculate $n_i$s ?

Comment: @jaroslaw count the number of occurrences of each letter and store the counts in an array. Then count the occurrences of each value in the array and store those counts in a second array. The second array is $n$.

Comment: I see, but is there a simple formula? Because for large $N$ (10,11,12) this array might be very big.

Comment: The arrays have $N$ elements each.

Comment: For $N=12$ I've found 37 unique patterns (5 for triples, 11 for quadruples, 11 for fives and 10 for sixs) , so more than $N$.

Comment: And there are still 7s, 8s,... , 12s to find.

Comment: Oh, you want to know how to calculate the patterns, not the $n_i$.  This is not hard to do but I can't explain it in a comment.  [The number of patterns is exponential](https://oeis.org/A000041) in $N$, but not unmanageably so.  You can see the source code at https://perl.plover.com/misc/enumeration/enumeration.pl ; the name of the function is `patterns` and it is only about seven lines long.  Or see [Chapter 5 of _Higher-Order Perl](https://hop.perl.plover.com/book/) for an explanation, or one of the sources in the OEIS page.

Comment: Note that even for large $N$, you do not have to calculate all the patterns and store them.  It is not hard to calculate them one at a time, each one from the previous, so that only one is in memory at any time.  The _Higher-Order Perl_ link above explains how to do this.  Also, for $n=12, d=6$ there are [58 patterns](https://perl.plover.com/misc/enumeration/tabulate-dice.cgi?N=12&S=6&s=0), not 37.

Comment: @JaroslawMatlak [Here is a Python program](https://github.com/mjdominus/python-util/blob/master/math-misc/pattern.py) that implements a generator that produces the $n_i$ vectors one at a time, without first generating the letter patterns themselves.  For example, run with the argument `4` it produces successively the vectors $[0, 0, 0, 1];
[1, 0, 1];
[0, 2];
[2, 1];
[4]
$, and then quits.

Comment: @MJD thank you for explanation :)

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

You can compute the probability of not getting triple. The number $f_n$ of possibilities of not getting triples in $n$ throws is:
$$f_1 = \binom{6}{1}\\
f_2 = \binom{6}{2}2!+\binom{6}{1}\\
f_3=\binom{6}{3}3!+\binom{6}{1}\binom{5}{1}\frac{3!}{2!}\\
f_4=\binom{6}{4}4!+\binom{6}{1}\binom{5}{2}\frac{4!}{2!}+\binom{6}{2}\frac{4!}{2!2!}\\
f_5=\binom{6}{5}5!+\binom{6}{1}\binom{5}{3}\frac{5!}{2!}+\binom{6}{2}\binom{4}{1}\frac{5!}{2!2!}\\
f_6=\binom{6}{6}6!+\binom{6}{1}\binom{5}{4}\frac{6!}{2!}+\binom{6}{2}\binom{4}{2}\frac{6!}{2!2!}+\binom{6}{3}\frac{6!}{2!2!2!}\\
f_7=\binom{6}{1}\frac{7!}{2!}+\binom{6}{2}\binom{4}{3}\frac{7!}{2!2!}+\binom{6}{3}\binom{3}{1}\frac{7!}{2!2!2!}\\
f_8=\binom{6}{2}\frac{8!}{2!2!}+\binom{6}{3}\binom{3}{2}\frac{8!}{2!2!2!}+\binom{6}{4}\frac{8!}{2!2!2!2!}\\
f_9=\binom{6}{3}\frac{9!}{2!2!2!}+\binom{6}{4}\binom{2}{1}\frac{9!}{2!2!2!2!}\\
f_{10} = \binom{6}{4}\frac{10!}{2!2!2!2!}+\binom{6}{5}\frac{10!}{2!2!2!2!2!}\\
f_{11}=\binom{6}{5}\frac{11!}{2!2!2!2!2!}\\
f_{12}=\binom{6}{6}\frac{12!}{2!2!2!2!2!2!}$$
For $k>13$ we have $f_k=0$

The number of all possible throws $\omega_n$ is:
$$\omega_n=6^n$$
Now you can compute the probability of not getting triple:
$$p_n=\frac{f_n}{\omega_n}$$
and probability of getting triple:
$$q_n=1-p_n$$

Comment: Thanks a lot for the suggestion. It does allow to solve the "triples" problem but not the "or better" part. Still pretty interesting take on the problem.

Comment: Actually this solution consider "or better" as a triple. $p_n$ denotes the number of events, where there at most pairs.

Comment: What am I getting wrong? If $n=5,$ then $f_5 = 6+60+60=126$ and $\omega_n = 252,$ so $q_n = p_n = .5.$ Which is already larger than @MJD's answer. (Seems _exactly_ a triple has probability $\approx 0.19.)$

Comment: @BruceET You're right - my answer was not complete (I comsidered each situation as one, while there are more possibilities of throwing AAABB for given A and B than AAAAA. I've edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly, you're looking for a generalization of the binomial distribution to $n > 2$ where $n$ is the number of possible classes. The term for this is [a multinomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_distribution).

We can view a $n = 2$ side analog of a dice as a coin. The probability of a single outcome is a Bernoulli distribution (e.g. $\Pr(H)$). The probability of multiple outcomes is a Binomial distribution (e.g. $\Pr(HT)$).

For $n > 2$, the probability of a single outcome is a Categorical distribution (e.g. $\Pr(1)$). The probability of multiple outcomes is a Multinomial distribution (e.g. $\Pr(1126)$).

Remember that a multinomial distribution will only tell you the distribution of, say 5 of the rolls being $1$. So if you're looking for pairs or triplets regardless of the class -- whether its 1 or 2, you don't care -- you have to multiply your probability (if its a fair dice) or construct a sum in the case the dice is not fair.